# When I edit a model and remake the the database, why does my admin page look like this?

Tags: django, django-admin

[image: silly admin]

I can access localhost/blog and localhost/comic , but not localhost/blog/BlogPost or localhost/comic/ComicPost, preventing me from adding posts.  Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: How did you "remake the database" exactly?

Comment: I deleted the old one, and made a new one, then ran syncdb

Comment: In settings.py , if DEBUG = False, then it looks like this.  Everything works and behaves normally if DEBUG = True